# Bash script to check is a directory is modifed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This has probably been created before and better than mine. I have a directory where files are created for a few milliseconds before being removed. I researched and couldn't find what I was looking for so I made something to do it and added a few more features.

How it works:

you run the script, input the directory, and input the time you want it to run from 10 seconds to 6000 seconds (1 hour). It validates what you enter to make sure the directory is real and you don't exceed or go below that time. using sdiff -s it will compare the state of the directory when the script began to a new version of it ever 0.001 seconds. If there are changes it will tell you.

I wanted to share it since other may find it useful, and more importantly ask if you guys had improvements. I have been doing a lot of self-taught (mostly using stack exchange) bash scripting for almost a year and I really love it. I am always looking to improve me code. I am new to interactive scripts so if you guys have recommendations for input validation I'd love to hear it. I couldn't figure out how to get the "if" statements for time in seconds combined to check for anything less than 10 and greater than 6,000 despite trying a lot of things so I just made them separate. The "sed" portions are kind of wonky here and I didn't do a great job optimizing. I just worked on them until the output was what I wanted.

EDIT: I don't have inotify and I don't think I could get it on this locked down system.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Directory Check Script
# Created 13 Aug 2022

CLISESSID=$$
export CLISESSID


### DEFINE A LOCATION WHERE FILES CAN BE TEMPORARILY MADE ###
tmp=/tmp


temp1=$tmp/temp1.txt
temp2=$tmp/temp2.txt

echo "This script will check a directory to see if any files were added for the length of time you specify"

read -ep 'What is the full directory you would like to verify? ' dir
if [ ! -d "$dir" ] ; then
    echo "Directory does not exist. Exiting."
    exit
fi
read -ep '(This must be between 10-6000. i.e 5 minutes = 300, 10 minutes = 600, 1 hour = 6000) 
How many seconds would you like to check for? ' seconds
if [[ "$seconds" -lt 10 ]] ; then
    echo "Seconds must be between 10 and 6000"
    exit
fi
if [[ "$seconds" -gt 6000 ]] ; then
    echo "Seconds must be between 10 and 6000"
    exit
fi
echo "checking $dir for $seconds seconds."

ls --full-time $dir | tail -n +2 > $temp1

SECONDS=0
echo "Checking for changes to $dir every 0.001 seconds for $seconds seconds."
until [[ $(ls --full-time $dir | tail -n +2) != $(cat "$temp1") ]] > /dev/null 2>&1
    do
    if (( SECONDS > $seconds ))
       then
       echo "Exceded defined time of $seconds seconds. Exiting."
       exit 1
    fi
       sleep 0.001
       done
    ls --full-time $dir | tail -n +2 > $temp2
if [[ $(sdiff -w 400 -s $temp1 $temp2 | grep " |" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]  ; then
    echo "
File has been modified in $dir:"
    sdiff -w 400 -s $temp1 $temp2 | sed 's/|/\n/' | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed '1~ i Before:' | sed '3~ i After:' | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
fi

if [[ $(sdiff -w 400 -s $temp1 $temp2 | grep " >" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]  ; then
    echo "
File has been added to $dir:"
    sdiff -w 400 -s /tmp/temp1.txt /tmp/temp2.txt | sed 's/>/\n/' | grep -v " |" | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed '1~ i Added file:' | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed '/./!d'
fi

if [[ $(sdiff -w 400 -s $temp1 $temp2 | grep " <" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]  ; then
    echo "
File has removed modified in $dir:"
    sdiff -w 400 -s $temp1 /$temp2 | sed 's/</\n/' | grep -v " |" | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed '1~ i Removed file:' | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed '/./!d' | sed 's/ *$//'
fi
rm -f $temp1 $temp2
```

Comment: hey just FYI, there are 3600 seconds in an hour, 6000 seconds is almost 2 hours

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent [`inotify`](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools)?

Comment: Macko, good catch I don't know why I didn't check that.

Comment: user1934428, kinds of yeah haha. I don't have it on my locked down system or else I would have just used it.

Comment: I recommend posting on https://reddit.com/r/bash or maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com and hopefully you will get some useful feedback. Start by quoting variables like `"$temp1"`.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ may provide some useful feedback as well.